# Running same job in different MultiJob phases

Tags: testing, jenkins

### What I want to do

Well, if it was a bash script, it would be something like this:

```bsh
# run "foo" test
prepare_test_machine --profile=foo
run_test
# run "bar" test
prepare_test_machine --profile=bar
run_test
# run "baz" test
prepare_test_machine --profile=baz
run_test
```

I don't need no parallelization, since all tests actually run on the very same box.

### What have I tried

I created two jobs, one for *prepare_test_machine* and one for *run_test*.  *prepare_test_machine* accepts just one parameter, and *run_test* does not accept any--it can simply assume that the preceding job has set everything up.

Next I set up a MultiJob, that calls each step as a MultiJob phase, passing parameters only where necessary.

### What is wrong?

While it does seem to do the work I need it behaves in a completely confusing way:  After I start the MultiJob:

1. *all* prepare jobs sart to "blink",
2. after they finish, all report the same result and duration in the MJ view,
3. then *all* run jobs sart to "blink",
4. and behave the same as the prepare jobs,
5. which repeats for each pair, results of each run being written to all similar
   runs, instead of just the single phase in the MJ view.

So for example, if "baz" takes 97s and 8s respectively, "bar" takes 87s and 11s, and "baz" takes 111s and 25s I'd expect to see something like this ("#" mark the phase labels):

```
+-----------------------------------+
| # prepare foo                     |
| O   prepare_test_machine     97s  |
| # run foo                         |
| O   run_test                 8s   |
| # prepare bar                     |
| O   prepare_test_machine     87s  |
| # run bar                         |
| O   run_test                 11s  |
| # prepare baz                     |
| O   prepare_test_machine     111s |
| # run baz                         |
| O   run_test                 25s  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

but instead see:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| # prepare foo                     |
| O   prepare_test_machine     111s |
| # run foo                         |
| O   run_test                 25s  |
| # prepare bar                     |
| O   prepare_test_machine     111s |
| # run bar                         |
| O   run_test                 25s  |
| # prepare baz                     |
| O   prepare_test_machine     111s |
| # run baz                         |
| O   run_test                 25s  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

### Questions

Can this setup be tweaked so that it behaves the way I want?  Or I'm just using wrong tool for the job?  (I'm new to Jenkins, so I wouldn't be surprised).  If so, could anyone point me to the right direction?

(If it's possible, I'd like to keep the layout flat, i.e. avoid messy sub-projects or "run-after" triggers.)

Comment: why not just put your "if it was a bash script" code into a shell section in the jenkins job so that the foo bar baz conditions are run sequentially?

Comment: @Vorsprung ... or I could just stuff it all into a single bash script and run it using cron, right?  :D  But seriously, I want to retain some flexibility like running *only* run_test time to time.  Also there are some Jenkins-y things in each of the two jobs that due to security restrictions can't be easily done from the executor (which is where the bash script is run).

Answer (score 1):

This issue is documented ([Future obj not observed when same job executed parallel](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17799)) and I provided a [bug-fix](https://github.com/saschavet/tikal-multijob-plugin/tree/ISSUE-J-17799), unfortunately the fix isn't part of the latest version.

Comment: I don't quite understand the bug report, *but* from your screen I see that your layout is different than mine:  I have just one MultiJob with 6 phases each holding a single job (altering between prepare and run).  Your layout uses nesting: something like "one MJ with 3 phases, each holding another MJ with 2 phases"... Such layout makes more sense though, I'm going to think about it... :)

Comment: A different layout doesn't solve the issue: without the bug-fix MultiJob collects the "similar" jobs and observes only one of them. To get the expected behavior download and test the bug-fix (when you are familiar with git/github and maven).